# "Instapress" wordpress plugin widget (instagram pics)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, lightbox

I have som trouble to disply the "Instagram" lightbox (fancybox) in my sidebar on my wordpress site.
It shows below the "fixed" position header. I tried to change z-index and positioning but it doesn´t work.

Any simple solution?

Comment: I am sorry, my [telepathy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telepathy) powers are a bit off-synch today, and my [x-ray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_vision) vision device is in repairs ... (that means that If you want a "simple" solution, you have to provide more details , like link to the plugin, theme, or preferably, the live website where one can go and check the problem.)

Comment: Here is a link to live website. Try to "click" on the instagram pics in the sidebar, then you see the lightbox goes below the "Fixed" positioned header. http://www.magnustannfors.se/gadjos/

Answer (score 0):

It does not work for you because you have the `#headerFixed` z-index set to :

**`1000000`** ( Seriously ??? Is the client paying by z-index ?? )

line 174 :

```
#headerFixed {
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000000;
}
```

Try to change it to a more sane number (lets say 50 ).

Because the lightbox is "playing" around z-index 1100 , anything BELOW that should be ok .

Comment: It still not show on "top" of the header.. still the same problem.

Comment: that is strange , because when I load your site , it still is set to **1000000** ... If you will not change that , It will sure not work .